# Using "name the .. with"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

What should I use? I want to say we give the name xx-prog to the program (that I already described.

> [...] and we name the program with xx-prog.

Or,

> [...] and we name the program xx-prog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a preposition there, though stylistically you may want to indicate that *xx-prog* is a name but putting it in quotation marks or italicising it. *Name* is a ditransitive verb, and the objects are *the program* and *xx-prog*.

Just like if you were naming a person. Or a ship.

> I name this ship *Endeavour*, and may God bless all who sail in her.
>
> We named our son Lucy.